# How to use the module <format> of the c++20 standard with g++ 13.2.0 and Gnu Make 3.81 under Mac OS X Big Sur

Tags: c++, module, format, c++20, linker-errors

After 5 days... Can nobody give me a hint what is wrong with that? I have not found a solution for this problem yet!

---vvv---

I just started to read about the C++20 standard and wanted to try out modules. I installed g++ 13.2.0 and GNU Make 3.8.1 via Homebrew under Mac OS X Big Sur. On the gcc website is stated, that modules support is not yet finished and one has to:

1.) use -std=c++20 and -fmodules-ts flags,
2.) build the Standard Library Header Units first
3.) use -x c++-system-header flag when working with headers without suffixes.

So I created these two test files (main.cpp and makefile):

main.c:

```
import <cstdint>;
import <format>;
import <iostream>;
import <ostream>;
import <sstream>;
import <string>;

int main()
{
    // test module: cstdint
    uint64_t val { UINT64_C(42) };
    
    // test module: format
    // std::string fstr = std::format("The number {} is great!", 42);

    // test module: iostream
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    
    // test module: ostream
    std::cout << std::endl;
    
    // test module: sstream
    std::stringstream ss; ss << "C++20";

    // test module: string
    std::string str = "This is a string stream";

    return 0;
}
```

makefile:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

SHELL = /bin/sh

.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: .cpp .o

objects = main.o

mtest : stdlib $(objects)
    g++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -o mtest $(objects)

stdlib :
    g++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -x c++-system-header cstdint
    g++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -x c++-system-header format
    g++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -x c++-system-header iostream
    g++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -x c++-system-header ostream
    g++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -x c++-system-header sstream
    g++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -x c++-system-header string

main.o : main.cpp
    g++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -c main.cpp

.PHONY : clean
clean :
    -rm -rf gcm.cache
    -rm mtest $(objects)
```

Everything works fine when the line under 'test module: format' is commented out. BUT: If I try to use std::format and activate the line, I get a linker error.

error:

```
g++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -x c++-system-header cstdint
g++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -x c++-system-header format
g++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -x c++-system-header iostream
g++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -x c++-system-header ostream
g++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -x c++-system-header sstream
g++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -x c++-system-header string
g++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -c main.cpp
g++ -std=c++20 -fmodules-ts -o mtest main.o
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__ZNSt8__detail31__from_chars_alnum_to_val_tableILb0EE5valueE", referenced from:
      __ZNSt8__detail25__from_chars_alnum_to_valILb0EEEhh in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [mtest] Error 1
```

I have googled on so many sites and didn't find an appropriate solution. I have not much expertise in C++ programming and makefiles at all, so it is difficult to figure out what goes on there. Has anyone a solution for this?

I tried the listed code samples that import, compile and link all modules in the same way. I expected std::format to work, because all of the other modules work flawlessly. When I use std::format I get a linker error.

PS: I also tested the __cpp_lib_format macro for a value >= 201907 as stated in the SD-FeatureTest on the isocpp.org website. And I am sure, that I have a recent version.

PPS: I just added a user defined module. That works very well, too!

Greetings an thanks for help!
pocahontius

Comment: Sadly std::format is still not supported on XCode. It is always a pain in the arse. Took years until they included std::filesystem. Apple is slow on this. And i dont want to imagine how many years it will take until modules are supported. I know young people knowadays are so addicted to use the latest features but as a professional developer i tell you to stick with things that are at least a decade old. That said, you might be able to replace std::format with the open source fmt::format which is what i do in my code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am not using Xcode. I installed G++ 13.2.0 and Make 4.4.1 (not 3.81 as mentioned above) via terminal and homebrew. As I wrote, modules work fine, the only thing that does give a linker error is <format>. I looked up the support pages for g++ and it states that 13.2.0 has support for modules and format, so I think, I make something wrong when I compile, perhaps?